# How to add "async" to a route with a custom middleware?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I need to use `await` inside a route on Express, therefore it must be `async`. However, when I try to add `async` to the route, it does not work because I use a middleware.

```
api.get('/users/yop', CORS(CORSOPT), async, checkauth, (req, res) => {
  await GETDATA.getUsers(db.collection('users'));
  res.json(users[req.user]);
})
```

Middleware looks like this:

```
function checkauth(req, res, next) {
 ...
 next();
}
```

If `async` and `checkout` are separed by commas like in the code I posted, I get this error:
`await is only valid in async function`

If they are not separated by commas, my code editor marks it as syntax error:
[image]

How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax you're trying is not valid. `async` always goes with the function definition.

```js
api.get('/users/yop', CORS(CORSOPT), checkauth, async (req, res) => {
  await GETDATA.getUsers(db.collection('users'));
  res.json(users[req.user]);
})
```

should work. If `checkauth` too contains `await` statements, mark the *definition* of `checkauth` as async.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the arrow function as async directly using the keyword.

```js
api.get('/users/yop', CORS(CORSOPT), checkauth, async (req, res) => {
    await GETDATA.getUsers(db.collection('users'));
    res.json(users[req.user]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the "async" directly in-front of the function you are passing in, not the references to the other functions. If those needed async, they can have their own declarations when those functions are defined themselves.

```
api.get('/users/yop', CORS(CORSOPT), checkauth, async (req, res) => {
  await GETDATA.getUsers(db.collection('users'));
  res.json(users[req.user]);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [add async](https://codefibershq.com/blog/handling-promise-rejections-in-expressjs-nodejs-with-ease) to the callback function:

```
api.get('/users/yop', CORS(CORSOPT), checkauth, async (req, res) => {
  await GETDATA.getUsers(db.collection('users'));
  res.json(users[req.user]);
})
```

Also if you want checkauth to return a promise for any reason, this is where you put the async:

```
async function checkauth(req, res, next) {
 ...
 next();
}
```